# How to read .rodata from linked object files?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am trying to access an externally linked data segment in a C/C++ program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

extern void *__foo;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *foo = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(__foo);
    std::cout << std::addressof(foo) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The symbol table obtained with `objdump -t bar.o` has the  following

> 0000000000000000 g     O .rodata        0000000000004d05 __foo

And symbol table of executable after compiling has the following

> 000000000004a9c1 g     O .rodata        0000000000004d05              __foo

After compiling and executing the program I recieve the following results

```
0x7ffe616dbb30
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Valgrind provides the following output

```
0x1ffefffec0
==14359== Invalid read of size 1
==14359==    at 0x11B5CF: main (main.cc:9)
==14359==  Address 0x4cfd is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==14359== 
==14359==
```

The valgrind error makes sense as the data section is indeed not allocated by the program, but since I am only trying to read the data I believe I should be able to access it.

How can I read this data section?

Comment: You should also show the code defining `__foo` and its value (in other words: [mre] please).

Comment: @dratenik Unfortunately I can't do that as I do not have access to the source of that file.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that `__foo` contains a pointer to something? It would seem that it contains the bytes `fd 4c 00 00 00`... which go blam if interpreted as a pointer.

Comment: Or did you want to dump `__foo` itself? In that case just declare it as `extern char __foo[]` and print the contents of that.

Comment: @dratenik: 
yeah, that works. I just found that myself as well but would accept your answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that whatever `__foo` contains, it is not a valid pointer. If you are interested in the contents of __foo itself, declare it as `extern char __foo[]` and dump that.